# Is it possible to add another field to find and filter results from a mongodb database in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get a document back from a mongodb database but I want to only get the document where the username and the password equals to the values that I am passing in. I have the following code and my question is, how can I add another field (password) to filter the results? currently I am only filtering by username but I don't know how to add another field to search for:

```
public Employee getEmployee(String username, String password) {
    FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("Username", username));
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        //ArrayList<Object> o = new ArrayList<>(doc.values());
        e.setId(doc.get("_id").toString());
        e.setName(doc.get("Name").toString());
        e.setAddress(doc.get("Address").toString());
        e.setEmail(doc.get("Email").toString());
        e.setPhone(doc.get("Phone").toString());
        e.setUsername(doc.get("Username").toString());
        e.setPassword(doc.get("Password").toString());
    }
    return e;//Get the shoes
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `new BasicDBObject("Username", username).append("Password", password)`? Not sure that is accurate, but here's one with an explicit *and*: `new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("Username", username), new BasicDBObject("Password", password)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html) class's `append` method can be used to add mutiple criteria for the filter, as follows (this is just using another way).

```
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(new Document("Username", username).append("Password", password));
```

*-or-*

```
Document filter = new Document("Username", username).append("Password", password);
// -or-
Document filter = new Document().append("Username", username).append("Password", password);

FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and you can easily add another query in `BasicDBObject` check the JAVA API documentation for details:

https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html

Search for `append` method in this documentation, from that documentation you can `.append` in the previous object as follow:

```
public Employee getEmployee(String username, String password) {

    //  build the BSON object query
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Username", username).append("Password", password);
    // Execute the query
    FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(query);
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        //ArrayList<Object> o = new ArrayList<>(doc.values());
        e.setId(doc.get("_id").toString());
        e.setName(doc.get("Name").toString());
        e.setAddress(doc.get("Address").toString());
        e.setEmail(doc.get("Email").toString());
        e.setPhone(doc.get("Phone").toString());
        e.setUsername(doc.get("Username").toString());
        e.setPassword(doc.get("Password").toString());
    }
    return e;//Get the shoes
}
```

Or as suggested in the comment section by @ernest_k will also work.

References:

1. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html
2. https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html